# Address generation for bitcoin with Python error

Tags: python-3.x, bitcoin

I am trying to understand bitcoin with python and trying to create my own vanity address generator.

Below is a snippet of the while loop. I keep getting an error after the loop runs about 10 times. Any help would be highly appreciated. i have searched the forum and have found answers.

But they don't work. IE. i changed the

```
intermed = hashlib.sha256(string).digest()
```

a few times modifying the code but still the same result.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 38, in <module>
    compressed_address_base58check = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bitcoin/mai
n.py", line 452, in pubkey_to_address
    return bin_to_b58check(bin_hash160(pubkey), magicbyte)  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bitcoin/mai
n.py", line 334, in bin_hash160
    intermed = hashlib.sha256(string).digest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

```
while True:
  pk = binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(32)).decode('utf-8').upper()
  privkey = f"{pk:0>64}"
  pub = privtopub(privkey)   # Get pub addr from priv key
  addr = pubtoaddr(pub)   # Get the 1Btc... address
  decoded_private_key = bitcoin.decode_privkey(privkey, 'hex')
  wif_encoded_private_key = bitcoin.encode_privkey(decoded_private_key, 'wif')
  # Add suffix '01' to indicate a compressed private Key
  compressed_private_key = privkey + '01'
  # generate a WIF format from the compressed private key (WIF-compressed)
  wif_compressed_private_key = bitcoin.encode_privkey(bitcoin.decode_privkey(compressed_private_key, 'hex'), 'wif')
  # Multiply de EC generator G with the priveate key to get a public key point
  pubkey = bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, decoded_private_key)
  # Encode as hex, prefix 04
  hex_encoded_public_key = bitcoin.encode_pubkey(pubkey, 'hex')
  # Compress public key, adjust prefix depending on whether y is even or odd
  (public_key_x, public_key_y) = pubkey
  if public_key_y % 2 == 0:
    compressed_prefix = '02'
  else:
    compressed_prefix = '03'
  hex_compressed_public_key = compressed_prefix + bitcoin.encode(public_key_x, 16)
  print ('Compressed Public Key: ' + hex_compressed_public_key)
  # Generate compressedd bitcoin address from compressed public key 

  compressed_address_base58check = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key)
  print ("private key:           " + privkey )
  print ("uncompressed address:     "+ addr )
  print ('Compressed address:       ' + bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key))
  C_address = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key)
  U_address = addr
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode your `hex_compressed_public_key` to generate the address.

```
compressed_address_base58check = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(hex_compressed_public_key.encode('utf-8'))
```