# Compute compressed bitcoin address from private key

Tags: python, cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

I am starting to get an overview about bitcoin and wanted to write a very simple programme converting private keys into public, keys, addresses etc. However, for some private keys it suddenly fails when I try to compute the compressed address for them. The reason it fails as far as I can see is that the compressed public key I am passing to the function `bitcoin.pubkey_to_address()` is one digit too short. As it is one of the most famous bitcoin libraries I assume that there is a fundamental error in my understanding. Thus, the question: what am I doing wrong in computing the compressed bitcoin address from a private key?

I have installed the following library: `pip3 install bitcoin` in the minimal example below, I am using Python 3.8.5 on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
import bitcoin


class WalletWithBalance:
    def __init__(self, _private_key: str):
        self.private_key_uncompressed_hex: str = _private_key

        # public keys:
        self.public_key_uncompressed_as_x_y_tuple_hex = self.get_private_key_as_x_y_tuple()
        self.public_key_compressed_hex = self.get_compressed_public_key_hex()

        # addresses:
        self.address_compressed = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(self.public_key_compressed_hex)

    def get_public_key_as_raw_hex_str(self):
        public_key_as_raw_hex_str = bitcoin.encode_pubkey(self.public_key_uncompressed_as_x_y_tuple_hex, 'hex')
        return public_key_as_raw_hex_str

    def get_private_key_as_x_y_tuple(self):
        private_key_raw_decimal_number = bitcoin.decode_privkey(self.private_key_uncompressed_hex, 'hex')
        return bitcoin.fast_multiply(bitcoin.G, private_key_raw_decimal_number)

    def get_compressed_public_key_hex(self):
        (public_key_x, public_key_y) = self.public_key_uncompressed_as_x_y_tuple_hex
        return self.get_compressed_prefix(public_key_y) + bitcoin.encode(public_key_x, 16)

    @staticmethod
    def get_compressed_prefix(public_key_y):
        if public_key_y % 2 == 0:
            return "02"
        else:
            return "03"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wallet = WalletWithBalance(_private_key="0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c")
```

The stacktrace reads:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /foo/minimal_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/foo/minimal_example.py", line 36, in <module>
    wallet = WalletWithBalance(_private_key="0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c")
  File "/foo/minimal_example.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.address_compressed = bitcoin.pubkey_to_address(self.public_key_compressed_hex)
  File "/DoeJohn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bitcoin/main.py", line 452, in pubkey_to_address
    return bin_to_b58check(bin_hash160(pubkey), magicbyte)
  File "/DoeJohn/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bitcoin/main.py", line 334, in bin_hash160
    intermed = hashlib.sha256(string).digest()
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

Comment: did you check in documentation for `pybitcointools` if there is something about shorter addresses ?

Comment: I don't know if it is most popular library but it is very old - last version was released in 2014 - see [on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pybitcointools/). And maybe it doesn't work with shorter addresses. On its [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) you can see [link to newer version](https://github.com/primal100/pybitcointools) but created by different person and you have install it from GitHub.

Comment: @furas I have build my code following the book "Mastering bitcoin" where this library was recommended. Unfortunately `pybitcointools` itself is very poorly documented. I will try the Gitlab version for the very unlikely case that there is just a bug in the version of `pybitcointools` I have.

Comment: if there is no documentation then you may try to read source code - maybe there will be comments or `docstrings` - or you can see how function works and what other functions it uses, etc.. Eventually you may try to use `help(command)` to see `docstrings` without reading source code.

Comment: @furas: That I have all done. Vitalik Buterin (one of the fathers of Ethereum) who wrote this library was not a great friend of docstrings. I have just installed the latest version of your GitHub link which was from 2019, but the error persists.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas: Unfortunately in this case the traceback would be misleading, it simply tells you that unicode strings must be encoded in utf-8 before being hashed. However, the respective function is only reached as my compressed public key, which I passed to the function is one character too short. Thus, I think there is probably something wrong in my understanding of bitcoin addresses. Still, I will paste the traceback but it won't be much of a help.

Comment: `unicode strings must be encoded in utf-8` can means this code was created for Python 2 or someone forgot encode it in one place. OR maybe it runs different code for shorter address and only this code has this mistake (maybe nobody convert this part for Python 3).

Comment: @furas: I am starting to think that it might indeed be a bug in the code: you are probably right. The thing is I can see places in the code that distinguish between python2 and python3. Hence, it is meant to work for python2. I will just try to pass the encoded compressed public key and write a unit test with a public key I know the outcome for. Also, I think my question might be exactly the same as this user's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59139646/address-generation-for-bitcoin-with-python-error . Unfortunately it seems pretty orphaned.